# Where did SELinux go?

Tags: linux, kernel, compile, linux-kernel, selinux

I am compiling a new kernel, and want to enable SELinux but don't see it in menuconfig anywhere. The only framework under security options is Tomoyo.....so I ask, what happened to SELinux? Both 2.6.33.2 and 2.6.35.11 do not seem to have it present....

Comment: *** Humour *** The "great penguin" needs an occasional vacation too!  ;D

Comment: answer is that it needs auditing enabled first in generals setup.

Answer (score 2):

*[Copying Jace's comment into a full answer]*

Auditing must first be enabled from general setup. From [*Linux Kernel in a Nutshell*](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/ch09s06.html):

> SELinux requires that the networking
>   option be enabled. See the section
>   called “Networking” to enable this.
>
> SELinux also requires that audit be
>   enabled in the kernel configuration.
>   To do this:

```
 General setup
     [*] Auditing support
```

> Also, the networking security option must be
>   enabled:

```
 Security options
     [*] Enable different security models
     [*]   Socket and Networking Security Hooks
```

> Now it is possible to
>   select the SELinux option:

```
Security options
    [*] Enable different security models
    [*] NSA SELinux Support
```

> There are also a number of individual SELinux
>   options that you might wish to enable.
>   Please see the help for the individual
>   different items for more descriptions
>   on what they do in.

```
 Security options
     [*] Enable different security models
     [*] NSA SELinux Support
     [ ]   NSA SELinux boot parameter
     [ ]   NSA SELinux runtime disable
     [*]   NSA SELinux Development Support
     [*]   NSA SELinux AVC Statistics
     (1)   NSA SELinux checkreqprot default value
```